# How to get first match of string by Regular Expression?

Tags: regex

I have the following text string:

*$ABCD(file="somefile.txt")$' />Some more text followed by a dollar like this one)$. Some more random text*

I am trying to match the *$ABCD(file="somefile.txt")$* part of the string using a regular expression.

I am using this **(?=[$]ABCD[(]file=).*(?<=[)][$])** regular expression pattern to make the intended match. It's not working as expected because I am getting a match all the way to the second *)$* in the string.

For example, the match will be as follows:

*$ABCD(file="somefile.txt")$' />Some more text followed by a dollar like this one)$*

How should I modify the pattern to match to the end of the first occurrence of the *)$*?

Here is a good online regular expression engine tester:
http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try appending a `?` to the greedy `*`

```
(?=[$]ABCD[(]file=).*?(?<=[)][$])
```

[Lazy quantification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

> The standard quantifiers in regular expressions are greedy, meaning
>   they match as much as they can. Modern regular expression tools allow a quantifier to be specified as lazy (also known as > non-greedy, reluctant, minimal, or ungreedy) by putting a question mark after the quantifier

Comment: +1 for the lazy quantification! works with iOS' NSRegularExpression too

Answer (score 1):

You could just use this:

```
\$ABCD\(file="[a-z.]+"\)\$
```

to get `$ABCD(file="somefile.txt")$`.

Your problem was the `.*` bit, it was too general and thus matched everything up to the last `$`.

Answer (score 0):

I would advance you to use the second quote to define the end of the searched pattern: `[^"]*` will match to anything except `"`.

So the pattern for the file name would be: `\$ABCD\(file="([^"]*)`